# Как выполняется сортировка массива "пузырьком"

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Я понимаю, что есть специальная функция `sort()`, но мне захотелось написать её аналог самому - не получилось. Нашел в сети подобный скрипт, но не могу понять его логику. Могут ли знающие люди прокомментировать каждую строчку, подробно и, желательно, понятно расписать что есть что. Вот, собственно, и сам код:

```
$arr = array(4, 8, 1, 8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 43, 42);
$t = true;
while($t){
    $t = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++){
        if ($arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]){
            $temp = $arr[$i + 1];
            $arr[$i + 1] = $arr[$i];
            $arr[$i] = $temp;
            $t = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: закомментировать? да пожалуйста: 

    //$arr = array(4, 8, 1, 8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 43, 42);
    //$t = true;
    //while($t){
    //    $t = false;
    //    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++){
    //        if ($arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]){
    //            $temp = $arr[$i + 1];
    //            $arr[$i + 1] = $arr[$i];
    //            $arr[$i] = $temp;
    //            $t = true;
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

Comment: Блин, ну ПРОкомментировать, понятно же, к чему шутки?

Comment: Так! не петросяним. Один из немногих вопросов, который даже если учзад, вполне нормально вписывается в тематику. Автор показал что уже сделал и попросил помочь. Заметь: он не просил ни строчки кода за него написать.

Comment: @DreamChild, Петрорсян.jpg

@andreyqin, [вот][1] [несколько][2] [визуализаций][3] алгоритмов сортировки. Конечно, не совсем то, что вы просите, но поможет представить, что именно происходит при сортировке массивов разными алгоритмами.

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/117200/
  [2]: http://blgo.ru/tools/alg/sort/
  [3]: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: @DreamChild выношу на правах модератора предупреждение за неуместный флуд.

Comment: >написать её аналог самому - не получилось. Нашел в сети подобный скрипт

Уверен, что не сам. Но он сам нашел. Это тоже не так часто встречается.

Comment: @Barmaley, хорошо, я поясню свою мысль с комментариями чуть подробнее. Целью этой потросянской шутки было не смищно пошутить. Мысль тут была иная - если человек просит прокомментировать каждую строчку кода, который он якобы написал, то напрашивается резонный вопрос - а он ли автор этого кода? Почему автор не понимает им же написанного? Почему он, будучи автором кода, не скопирует один из миллионов примеров реализации этого метода и посмотрит сои ошибки? 
Просто не считаю уместным тут разбор домашних заданий за нерадивых студентов. Если кого обидел - извините.

Comment: @DreamChild у вас достаточно прав, чтобы самому закрыть вопрос если считаете его неуместным - это первое. Второе: издёвками делу не поможешь - это приводит только к агрессии (вспоминаю недавние матерные посты про вас). Держите себя в руках и все.

Comment: @Barmaley матерные посты про меня - это забавно. Но не делает чести тому, кто их писал, и говорит только об уровне культуры и низком самообладании этого человека. Я все же никогда не захожу за рамки приличия, и матом никого не крою. Смею даже предположить, что ответы я обычно даю вполне квалифицированные. Но думаю, вам не хуже, чем мне известно, что немалая часть здешних пользователей - нерадивые школьники, ищущие того, кто бы бесплатно бы сделал за них работу. 
Если я чем-то обидел @andreyqin то мои самые искренние ему извинения - надеюсь, я был неправ в его отношении

Comment: @DreamChild, все нормально. На самом деле я только учусь и понимаю, что подобного рода вопросы здешние старожилы не совсем одобряют.

Comment: @andreyqin тогда еще раз извините, я был неправ

Comment: не очень оптимальная реализация - с каждой итерацией while как минимум на одну проверку в конце цикла for можно уменьшить, так как там в любом случае будет самый большой элемент

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array(4, 8, 1, 8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 43, 42);//Исходный массив
$t = true;//можно ли еще сортировать
while($t){
    $t = false;//для начала, считаем, что нельзя
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++){// пробегаем по всему массиву, кроме последнего элемента
        if ($arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]){// если элемент, на который мы смотрим больше следующего
            /*1*/$temp = $arr[$i + 1];//это три действия для обмена местами элементов
            /*2*/$arr[$i + 1] = $arr[$i];//---//---
            /*3*/$arr[$i] = $temp;//пузырек всплывает на одну позицию вверх.
            $t = true;//раз что-то изменили, есть шанс, что сортировка еще не окончена
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Да пожалуйста:

```
$arr = array(4, 8, 1, 8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 43, 42);
$t = true;
while($t){ //циклим пока есть чего
    $t = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) - 1; $i++){ //по всем элементам массива
        if ($arr[$i] > $arr[$i + 1]){ //сравниваем 2 соседних элемента массива
            $temp = $arr[$i + 1];     //если один из них больше другого
            $arr[$i + 1] = $arr[$i];  //меняем их местами
            $arr[$i] = $temp;         //то есть "всплывает пузырек"
            $t = true;                //продолжаем циклить
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А ещё в PHP можно вместо

```
$temp = $arr[$i + 1];
$arr[$i + 1] = $arr[$i];
$arr[$i] = $temp;
```

Написать

```
list($arr[$i],$arr[$i+1])=array($arr[$i+1],$arr[$i]);
```

А ещё наверное можно использовать **break** и **continue**